# reading the input data in diferent lines

Tags: python, input, user-input

How can I write a piece of code in python that read the number in different lines and return the sum of them?

input data :

1
1
0
3
1
0

cod : ?   sum ()

output: 6

How python  function can read these number in diffrent lines?
3
3
6
4
5
9

Comment: e.g. `sum(map(int, text.split()))`.

Comment: "different lines" is unclear. Different lines in a text file? Multiple inputs in the console?